# Git settings configured for Linux on Windows computer

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I'm trying to configure my Git account run automatically authenticate via ssh however I am having problems with the publickey

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/aamcarr/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
```

When I first installed it, I think I chose the wrong settings and no matter how many times I retry installing, it still wont configure for the Windows computer..

I have tried multiple times to set up the SSH key and to add it to my Gerrit account but it still fails..

How can I update the git configuration file manually to fix this?

It seems to be trying to create the ssh key under:

```
Could not create directory '/home/aamcarr/.ssh'
```

but the actual key is generated under:

```
 c/Users/aamcarr/.ssh/known_hosts
```

How can I fix this??

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: Whatever shell you are using, install key for that shell